# Extract midpoint coordinates from TIFFs (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, coordinates

I have a large collection (>20000) of georeferenced satellite imagery tiles in TIFF format. Each of them has a size of 64x64 pixels.

[image]

Is there a way to extract the lat/lon coordinates of the midpoint of each tile and store them all in one table?

Comment: Gdalinfo returns also the coordinates of the center of the image but probably you want something that is more easy to use in a script. Then study https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/apps/gdalinfo_lib.cpp, from  GDALInfoReportCorner - "center"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never tried this for such a huge amount of rasters; hope this works:

1. GDALTileIndex (`Raster > Miscellaneous > Tile Index`) on your raster
2. Centroids (`Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroids`) on the tile polygons (from Step 1)
3. Add Geometry Attributes (`Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`) on the centroids (from Step 2)